# entity framework will add foreign key but not modify

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have HomeMadeItems that contains a reference to a Location object. So when entity framework code first migrations created my db, foreign key. Woo Hoo. Here is the code that saves an item:

```
    public int SaveHomeMadeItem(HomeMadeItem mod)
    {
        var _loc = this.GetLocation(mod.Location.Id);
        using (var s = new InventoryEntityFramework())
        {
            s.Locations.Attach(_loc);
            mod.Location = _loc;

            // returns the PK integer
            if (mod.Id == 0) // new record
            {
                s.InventoryItems.Add(mod);
                s.SaveChanges();
                return mod.Id;

            }
            else
            {
                // TODO: figure out why I cannot change location 
                s.InventoryItems.Attach(mod);
                s.Entry(mod).State = EntityState.Modified;
                s.Entry(mod.Location).State = EntityState.Modified;
                s.SaveChanges();
                return mod.Id;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is called from a controller which is called from a view where the location comes from a dropdown and gives me just an id, not an actual location object. So I get the correct location object and attach it to the context, and give it to my model. You see it before the if statement that decides on add or edit based on the presence of the item's PK.

The add code works great. But if I attempt to edit an item, the other properties will save correctly but not the foreign key for the item's location.

I have seen this asked elsewhere but not answered. Hope to find some help.

Thanks

Comment: You can do `mod.LocationID = myID` instead of doing a retrieve for the object

Comment: `mod.Location.Id` is already set, so there's even no need at all to do anything with `Location`.

Comment: Removing that does not solve the problem.